# Error when creating a case

Tags: apex, case

I'm using the following code to create a case in an Apex class:

```
Case newCase = new Case();

newCase.RecordTypeId = idList[0].Id;
newCase.Subject = staticValues.get(Type).get('Subject');
newCase.Type = staticValues.get(Type).get('Type');
newCase.Task_Type__c = staticValues.get(Type).get('TaskType');

newCase.OwnerId = '32fgqxn332sa';


if (FetchedContactId != '') {
    newCase.ContactId = FetchedContactId;
}

if (FetchedAccountId != '') {
    newCase.AccountId = FetchedAccountId;
}


newCase.Description = 'test';

insert newCase;
```

However after submission I receive a strange error message:
"FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION"
"Only Account sites are allowed."

What can cause this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a custom lookup filter defined on the `AccountId` field on Case.

Go to Object Manager → Case → Fields & Relationships → Account Name.

Check whether there are any lookup filters defined.

To resolve your error, you'll either need to remove the lookup filter, or make sure that every account you use meets the filter criteria.

For more information see here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384756&type=1

Comment: Yes it seems like it's a lookup field: Lookup(Account). How should I resolve this error? I've tried to create a case with a different account and it worked.

Comment: Remove the filter or make sure every account you populate it with meets the filter criteria

Comment: Thanks for the help!